# How can I automatically add a watcher which has been assigned to a "Tester" field in Jira when creating or editing issue?

Tags: jira

I want to add to JIRA (v6.4.11) next behavior: if person is set as a tester or code reviewer during issue create/edit I need to add person to issue watchers. And vise versa: if person is removed from code reviewers/testers we need to remove this person from watchers list. How can I achieved this?

Answer (score 1):

Use the free add-on [JIRA Watcher Field](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.burningcode.jira.issue.customfields.impl.jira-watcher-field/server/overview)
By editing this field you can add/remove watchers from the issue, and you can edit it via scripts (events, behavior plugin, post-functions, etc.)

Here is an example using the Behaviours add-on (part of the ScriptRunner plugin).
First, add a custom field called 'Issue Watchers' of type Watcher Field (available from the Jira watcher plugin) to your screen. Then, create a behaviour, add the 'Tester' field to it, and add the following code to the 'serverside script' section.

```
FormField testerField = getFieldById("Tester")
FormField watchersField = getFieldByName("Issue Watchers")
String testerUser = testerField.getValue()
String watchers = watchersField.getValue()

watchers = watchers + "," + testerUser
watchersField.setFormValue(watchers)
```

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand how can I edit "Jira Watcher Field" via scripts or etc. (events, behavior plugin, post-functions, etc.)? Please, explain if you can =(

Comment: I've edited my answer to include an explanation how to do it using the behavior add-on. Hope it helps...